# More Than 4 Dynamic Workspaces in Gnome 45

Tags: fedora, gnome

In Gnome 45, dynamic workspaces only happen to work up to a number of four. There seems to be a hard limit.

How can I increase this limit without switching to a fixed number of workspaces?

Comment: Try *Configuration → Multitasking* and check that the selected option is *Dynamic workspaces* instead of *Fixed number of workspaces*.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity Of course this is the case, as implied above.

Comment: I think the implication is not that clear, since you didn't mention that you had that configuration set explicitely. IMO you should [edit] the question and clarify exactly what are your settings, don't *imply* anything. I'm right now with GNOME 45 (in SUSE Tumbleweed) and there's no hard limit in DW.

Comment: What I mean is that the question seems to go around the problem instead of laying it out directly, which can be less helpful to you. *"Dynamic workspaces not working correctly in GNOME 45"* as title for example would point to the problem, *"More than 4..."* seems like asking how to do something, instead of describing that something is not working as it should.